# Restriction on vector fields

Tags: vector-fields

The 2D vector field (x,-y) does not transform like a vector under rotation(Arfken Vol. 1)! Does this mean we cannot have such a vector field physically?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't transform like a vector? A vector transforms like a vector by definition. Details please.

Comment: $V'_x=V_x cos \phi+V_y sin \phi$ , $V'_y=-V_x sin \phi+V_y cos \phi$  according to this  the transformd vector is $(x cos \phi-y sin \phi, -x sin \phi-y cos \phi)$ which is not $(x',-y')$ as it should be

Comment: In addition to rotating the vectors you also have to rotate the coordinates: $V'(\vec{r}')= \hat{R} V(\vec{r})$, where $\vec{r}' = R \vec{r}$.

Comment: yes if you do that you will not get $(x',-y')$

Comment: That's okay. It's [**not**](http://i.imgur.com/ZPvMHSS.png) a rotationally invariant vector field. There is no reason in general that you should get back the same thing.

Comment: Why does Arfken claim it is not a vector according to tensor transformations?

Comment: I don't know. Could you be more specific in your reference? Do you mean "Mathematical Methods for Physicists"? What chapter?

Comment: yes this is an old version I have, first chapter : vector analysis

Comment: I'm not finding any (legal) copies online so I'll have to go to the uni library to track this down, so sorry, not today. If you or somebody else could post more context of the text in question that would definitely help. But in general there are no restrictions on the form of a vector field.

Comment: @MichaelBrown I'd be interested to get your comments on my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to address the important concepts at play here in three dimensions.

The issue here is to get straight the distinction between any function $\mathbf v:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$, which we'll call a **vector field**, and an object that in addition to being a vector field in this sense, *transforms* in some prescribed way.  To mathematically describe/formalize the latter sort of object, let me first introduce the following definition:

For any vector field $\mathbf v$, and for any rotation (special orthogonal transformation) $R$, we define a **rotated vector field** $\mathbf v^R$ by
$$
  \mathbf v^R(\mathbf x) = R \mathbf v(R^{-1} \mathbf x)
$$
This definition is precisely the mathematical formalization of what most people think of when they think of rotating a vector field.

We now define a **3-vector field** as a function $\mathbf f(\mathbf v_1, \dots, \mathbf v_n):\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ depending on a finite number of vector fields $\mathbf v_i$ such that for any rotation $R$,
$$
  \mathbf f(\mathbf v_1^R, \dots, \mathbf v_n^R) = \mathbf f(\mathbf v_1, \dots, \mathbf v_n)^R
$$

The idea here is that a 3-vector field is a vector field constructed out of a bunch of other vector fields such that if each of the constituent vector fields out of which it is built are rotated, then that is equivalent to just rotating the 3-vector field itself.

As an example, consider the function $\mathbf f(\mathbf{v})$ defined by
$$
  \mathbf f(\mathbf{v}) = \nabla\times\mathbf v
$$
In other words, $\mathbf f(\mathbf{v})$ is just the curl vector field.  Is it a 3-vector field according to the definition above?  Let's check:
\begin{align}
  f(\mathbf{v}^R)(\mathbf x)
&= \nabla\times \mathbf v^R(\mathbf x) \\
&=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(R\mathbf v(R^{-1}\mathbf x))_k \mathbf e_i \\
&= \epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(R_{kn} v_n(R^{-1}\mathbf x)) \mathbf e_i \\
&= \epsilon_{ijk}R_{kn}\partial_j(v_n(R^{-1}\mathbf x)) \mathbf e_i \\
&=\epsilon_{ijk}R_{kn}(\partial_m v_n)(R^{-1}\mathbf x)\partial_j(R^{-1}\mathbf x)_m \mathbf e_i\\
&= \epsilon_{ijk}R_{kn}(\partial_m v_n)(R^{-1}\mathbf x)\partial_j(R^{-1}_{m\ell} x_\ell) \mathbf e_i\\
&= \epsilon_{ijk}R_{kn}(\partial_m v_n)(R^{-1}\mathbf x) R_{jm}\mathbf e_i \\
&= R_{i\ell}\epsilon_{\ell m n}(\partial_m v_n)(R^{-1}\mathbf x)\mathbf e_i \\
&= R(\nabla\times \mathbf v)(R^{-1}\mathbf x) \\
&= f(\mathbf v)^R(\mathbf x)
\end{align}
or in summary
$$
  \mathbf f(\mathbf v^R) = \mathbf f(\mathbf v)^R
$$
so, indeed, the curl of a vector field *is* a 3-vector field!  Now, let's return to your example.  Let's take a 3D analog and define a function $\mathbf f(\mathbf v)$ by
$$
  \mathbf f(\mathbf v)(\mathbf x) = (v_1(\mathbf x), -v_2(\mathbf x), v_3(\mathbf x))
$$
Is this a 3-vector field?  Namely, if we invert only one of the coordinates, then is the resulting vector field a 3-vector field according to our definition?  I claim that no, it is not.  To see this, consider the rotation $R$ that leaves the $z$ axis fixed, but that rotates in the $x$-$y$ plane by $\pi/2$ clockwise.  I'll leave it to you to check that
$$
  \mathbf f(\mathbf v^R)(x,y,z) = (-v_2(y,-x,z),-v_1(y, -x, z), v_3(y, -x, z))
$$
while
$$
  \mathbf f(\mathbf v)^R(x,y,z) = (v_2(y,-x,z),v_1(y, -x, z), v_3(y, -x, z))
$$
so that for this rotation $R$,
$$
  \mathbf f(\mathbf v_R)\neq \mathbf f(\mathbf v)^R
$$
and therefore this particular $\mathbf f(\mathbf v)$ is not a 3-vector!

I think this is rigorously the meaning of what Arfken is trying to say.

**Physical Interpretations**

You might ask why the definition of a 3-vector field given above is useful in physics.  Well here's the main idea.  Let's say that we measure a certain physical vector field using some apparatus, like the velocity field $\mathbf v$ on the surface of a lake for instance.  Then given this velocity field, one could compute the curl of this field $\mathrm{curl}(\mathbf v)$.  Now suppose that we were to rotate our measuring apparatus, then we would measure the rotated velocity field $\mathbf v^R$.  We could now calculate the curl $\mathrm{curl}(\mathbf v^R)$ of this rotated vector field, but because, as we showed above, the curl of a vector field is a 3-vector field, we could just as easily compute the rotated curl $\mathrm{curl} (\mathbf v)^R$, and we would get the same answer.  So in some sense, a 3-vector can be interpreted as a computed physical quantity which rotates in the same way as measured physical quantities.

Comment: I've never understood why people leave out translations when defining a 3-vector field.

Comment: @LarryHarson Hmmm yeah interesting observation.  I've never really thought about that.  I see no reason why we couldn't include translations in the definition in principle.  Except I suppose that if we did, then the curl, for example, would not be a 3-vector field since the derivative would kill the translation.  Actually I think that might be a significant point.  I'll think about it and see if I come to any other conclusions.

Comment: @joshphysics I think this is good. Seperating the transformations of direction and coordinates is confusing.

Comment: @LarryHarson I think translations are treated seperately is that it is trivial to do so and doesn't add anything: to translate a vector field you just translate the arguments. There is nothing specifically "vectorial" about that. The Euclidean group (of translations + rotations) is a semi-direct product of the translation and rotation groups: $E_3 \sim \mathbb{R}_{3}\rtimes\mathrm{SO}\left(3\right)$. So once you understand the representations of the rotation group $\mathrm{SO}\left(3\right)$ you immediately get reps of the Euclidean group for free. This is Wigner's "little group" idea.

Answer (score 1):

Transforming the positions and rotating the vector field are two different things.

Let $p$ be a point--for instance, $p = x e_1 + y e_2$, with $e_1, e_2$ being the usual Cartesian basis vectors.  We can define a transformation $f(p) = p' = x' e_1 + y' e_2$.

Now then, let $A(p)$ be a vector field--in our case, $A(p) = x e_1 - y e_2$.  As a vector field, $A$ can be considered as the derivative of some curve through the point $p$.  Let $c(\tau,p)$ be such a curve.  Then $A = \partial c/\partial \tau$ for some curve $c$.  There are necessarily different curves through each point $p$, but such curves always exist.

It is this construction that is crucial to understanding the transformation properties of vector fields.  Let us now consider $c' = f \circ c$, which is a family of curves in the primed space.  The chain rule then tells us that

$$\frac{\partial c'}{\partial \tau} \Big|_{p'} = \frac{\partial c}{\partial \tau} \cdot \nabla f \Big|_p$$

The object $a \cdot \nabla f$ for any vector $a$ is special--we call it the "differential" of $f$, or the "Jacobian".  Denote this as $\underline f(a)$, and we get

$$\frac{\partial c'}{\partial \tau} \Bigg|_{p'} = \underline f \left[\frac{\partial c}{\partial \tau} \right]_{p}$$

Or, more concisely,

$$A'(p') \equiv \underline f(A[p])$$

Linear transformations are special--they obey $f = \underline f$.  This means that $A'$ is **necessarily** just the rotation of $A$, but **evaluated at the rotated point also**.

Let's work out what this means for your vector field.  First work out the rotation:

$$\underline f(e_1) = e_1 \cos \theta + e_2 \sin \theta \\
\underline f(e_2) = e_2 \cos \theta - e_1 \sin \theta$$

Now work through the vector field:
$$\begin{align*} A(p) &= x e_1 - y e_2 \\
\underline f(A[p]) &= (x \cos \theta + y \sin \theta) e_1 + (x \sin \theta - y \cos \theta) e_2
\end{align*}$$

We need to convert this into the primed coordinates.  See that

$$x = x' \cos \theta + y' \sin \theta \\
y = y' \cos \theta - x' \sin \theta$$

Let's look at the first component.

$$x \cos \theta + y \sin \theta = x' \cos^2 \theta +2 y' \sin \theta \cos \theta - x' \sin^2 \theta = x' \cos 2\theta + y' \sin 2\theta$$

Similar logic applies for the other component, yielding

$$A'(p') = (x' \cos 2 \theta + y' \sin 2 \theta) e_1 + (x' \sin 2\theta - y' \cos 2\theta)e_2$$

You may be skeptical that this is the correct transformation of the vector field, but I assure you it is.  To check, pick the point $p = e_1$ and a vector $v = e_2$.  We know that $A(e_1) = e_1$, so that $v \cdot A = 0$.  If we transform both vectors according to $\underline f$, we should get $\underline f(v) \cdot \underline f(A) = 0$ as well--after all, a rotation should not change angles, should not change orthogonality.

Of course, it would be onerous to find the coordinates of $p = e_1$ in the primed frame.  It's much easier to see that

$$A'(p') = e_1 \cos \theta + e_2 \sin \theta$$

Similarly, $v' = \underline f(v) = e_2 \cos \theta - e_1 \sin \theta$.  This does indeed satisfy that $v' \cdot A' = 0$, as required.

In short, you cannot merely rotate the vector itself.  There are two rotations involved: one of the underlying positions, and then one of the vector field.  You should not expect that $A' = x' e_1 - y' e_2$.  This is not founded in the transformation law.  Perhaps this is what Arfken meant--that you can't be naive, expecting that even a simple rotation will preserve components of vectors and their relations to positions.  Once you derive the transformation law for vectors, though, it becomes a bit meaningless to say something is or is not a vector field. It's easy enough to impose this transformation law.  Perhaps Arfken meant to say that, given $A$ and $A'$ as prescribed in your question, it's clear that is *inconsistent* with the vector field transformation law.  Really, though, this strikes me as quite unclear.